# 'to have to use' and 'to use'

Tags: modal-verbs, semi-modals

> I am going **to have to use** it quite a lot today.
>   I am going **to use** it quite a lot today.

If both are correct, when should I use *to have to use* and when *to use*?

Comment: @agriz: I see John Lawler has commented as much on the same (now closed) question on ELU. You might like to note that the *pronunciation* is very often different when *have to* is used in the sense of *be obliged to*, as covered by [this ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/) (it's *"I HAFF to blah blah"*, and for past tense, *"I HAT to blah blah"*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construction *HAVE* + *to VERB* in your first sentence is what is called a 'semi-modal'; it replaces the 'full modal' auxiliary verb *must*, exactly as the semi-modal *BE going* + *to VERB* replaces the full modal *will*.

> I am going to use it = I will use it.
>   I have to use it = I must use it.

These semi-modals are more flexible than full modals. The full modals *can/could, may/might, shall/should, will/would, must* have no infinitive or participle forms, so they cannot act as the complements of other auxiliaries. For instance, you cannot say

> <sup>✲</sup> I will must use it.
>   <sup>✲</sup> I was musting use it.
>   <sup>✲</sup> I had musted use it.

If you want these sort of constructions you must substitute the semi-modal:

> <sup>OK</sup> I will have to use it.
>   <sup>OK</sup> I was having to use it.
>   <sup>OK</sup> I had had to use it.

So your two sentences mean different things:

> I am going to have to use it quite a lot today. = approximately, *It will be necessary for me to use it quite a lot today*.
>   I am going to use it quite a lot today. = *I will use it quite a lot today.*

---

Be careful to distinguish the construction *HAVE* + *to VERB* from the related construction *HAVE* + *NP* + *to VERB* (from which, historically, it derives).

> I have this tool to use. = *I have this tool (which) I am to use.*
>   I have a job to do.  = *I have a job (which) I am to do.*

Here *HAVE* is not an auxiliary but the lexical verb meaning *hold, possess*. The NP is the object of *to VERB*, and the implied subject of *to VERB* is the same as the subject of *HAVE*.

---

<sup>✲</sup>  *marks an utterance as unacceptable*
<sup>OK</sup>  *marks an utterance as acceptable*